# Remapping help-map

Tags: keymap, help

I'm trying to remap some keys in `help-map`, but the following does not work:

```
(define-key help-map [remap describe-mode] #'my-describe-mode)
```

Remapping in the global map does work, however:

```
(global-set-key [remap describe-mode] #'my-describe-mode)
```

Why is this? I can see that the value of `help-map` contains `describe-mode` when I call `describe-variable`:

```
help-map is a variable defined in `help.el'.
Its value is shown below.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Keymap for characters following the Help key.

Value: (keymap
 (remap keymap
    (describe-mode . my-describe-mode))
 ...
 (109 . describe-mode)
 ...
```

Does it have something to do with `C-h` being a prefix key?

Comment: `help-map` is a prefix keymap (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Prefix-Keymaps.html) and remapping doesn't work for this kind of keymap (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html).

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what keyboard combination you would like to press to trigger a particular function so we can suggest some solutions?

Comment: @xuchunyang I see. Is remapping through the global key the preferred method, then? Or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong According to `C-h k C-h m`, `C-h m` is in `global-map` (not `help-map`), so I think it is.

Comment: @xuchunyang: Please consider posting your helpful comment as an answer, which the OP can consider accepting. Thx.